# Docker is building but not showing data in browser

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, pip

I'm new to using Docker and this is my first project with it. I followed a tutorial to implement on a project i'm working on. I created a backend using python and django and am trying to containerize it and then deploy it. The application is building and being containerized, but when i go to see if my data is showing up, but it returns an error right now. Please take a look at the code and let me know if i've made any mistakes.

```
# Dockerfile

# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.5-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=nostaldjauser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=nostaldja
      - POSTGRESS_DB=nostaldja

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'nostaldja',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'nostaldja',
        'USER': 'nostaldjauser',
        'PASSWORD': 'nostaldja',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

```
(nostal-dja) bash-3.2$ docker-compose run web python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput
Starting nostal-dja_db_1 ... done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/code/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 87, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

Comment: What exactly is "an error"?

Comment: It's basically saying that it's not receiving the data.

Comment: Without a proper and complete description of the error there is no way we can help.

Comment: @klausD. i've posted the exact error. It seems the data has been unable to migrate into the Docker container properly.

Comment: @eyllanesc i went ahead and did the change you suggested, returned this message:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Feels like user error to me

Comment: @eyllanesc It is set to 'PORT': 5432

Comment: I think you should expose port 5432 similar to what you have done with port 8000